# Running Vagrant in Homestead. "Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I tried to use Homestead for Laravel 5 in Windows 10, but it's not working.

I first installed VirtualBox and later Vagrant. 
Then I executed the command

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

After that I cloned the Homestead repository into Users folder.

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead
```

Next I executed the file "init.bat", located in Homestead cloned folder.
In the book "Laravel:Up and Running" is write that the script will:

> "This will place Homestead’s primary configuration file,
>   Homestead.yaml, in a new ~/.homestead directory."

But a hidden Homestead directory is not created.

Despite that, I continued the process and modified the Homestead.yaml file located at "Users/sshann/Homestead" to:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:\Users\sshann\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\sshann\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:\Project\laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

And to finish I started vagrant in the directory "Users/sshann/Homestead" with

```
vagrant up
```

But then this error showed in CMD

```
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
```

I though that I might have messed up the Homestead.yaml, so I undid the changes, restore the file to its default content and re-run the last command again, but the same error showed again, so I suppose that the problem is not with the file.

I have the following directories:

```
C:\Users\sshann\Homestead
C:\Users\sshann\.VirtualBox
C:\Users\sshann\.vagrant.d
```

I searched for solutions, but none solved.

Do someone know what might be my problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: most of the times it is caused because of a wrong indentation of the yaml file, verify spaces and tabs in your file.

Comment: I checked the file again, but could not find anything. I have executed the init script again to reset the file and run "vagrant up" with the default content, but the same error shows up.